# Disable h1 and h2 from rich text editor combobox

Tags: headers, visual-editor

In the Wordpress control panel, when writing a new post, I would like to disable the Header 1 and Header 2 from the text formatting combobox, because I already use them on my theme (h1 for blog name and h2 for post titles), and would like to keep all headers inside a post with h3 or higher. Is that possible?

It doesn't matter for the case if the code can be edited in the HTML view. Also, I don't want to edit Wordpress internal files, so a hack for functions.php or a plugin would be great for this task, in order to preserve this change across future updates.

Thank you!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you can change lots of things about the tinyMCE editor at the tiny_mce_before_init filter.

http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons

the following will restrict your blockformats to p,h3,h4 and blockquote

```
function wpa_45815($arr){
    $arr['theme_advanced_blockformats'] = 'p,h3,h4,blockquote';
    return $arr;
  }
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpa_45815');
```

**EDIT for WordPress 3.9** [see link](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/506/custom-styles-for-wordpress-3-9/)

```
function wpa_45815($arr){
    $arr['block_formats'] = 'Paragraph=p;Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4';
    return $arr;
  }
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'wpa_45815');
```

Comment: Perfect! Didn't know I could control every aspect of the visual editor using a filter. Thanks for the tip, and for the reference link!

Comment: This simply works. I love it.

Comment: The syntax has changed as of wp 3.9 (probably). Now it should be `$init['block_formats'] = "Paragraph=p;Heading 3=h3;Heading 4=h4";`. See http://wordpress.org/support/topic/theme_advanced_blockformats-and-advanced_styles-are-not-recognized-in-tinymce-4

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick and dirty solution but it may work if your objective is to disable H1 and H2.

Add this code to your functions.php file

```
function custom_css() {
echo '<style type="text/css">
       #menu_content_content_formatselect_menu #mce_9, #menu_content_content_formatselect_menu #mce_10 {display:none;}
     </style>';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'custom_css');
```

Heading 1 and Heading 2 should be hidden now.

Comment: Your solution is also very good for what I want, it works. Just as a note, the mce_<number> can be different for each locale (in my case, Portuguese, the numbers were the 4 and 5 for h1 and h2 respectively). Thanks for your help!